# Dealing with self-signed SSL certificates

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

I deal a lot with self-signed SSL certificates as I deploy the systems in offline environments. The problem is that for example Chrome users has to deal with "dangerous site errors" etc, also if I want to even use GuzzleHttp library for connecting to any other service I have to setting secure to none. What's the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Register the certificate in whatever certificate store is used by the application that you require to trust the certificate.

Comment: There is no generic best way for  an unspecific "lots of self-signed certificates in offline environments". If you have control over all these certificates use a private PKI instead and add the relevant CA as trusted in all system- and application-specific trust stores (details depend on the applications used).  This way you trust all certificates issued by your PKI. If you don't have control over the certificates you have to add each one to the relevant trust store. Just switching off validation is definitely not the best way.

Comment: You can use a service like `xip.io` or `nip.io` to generate a certificate for an IP, so that e.g. `123.123.123.123` can be reached through `123.123.123.123.xip.io`. Not sure if you can use that for offline deployments but if you can't you might be able to adjust the `xip.io` idea for local use. You can find the `nip.io` source here: https://github.com/exentriquesolutions/nip.io

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **Selfsigned certificate** this can be made trusted to the specific system that you use. If others from your office uses it then they may need to add this Selfsigned certificate as **trusted** by adding it to their system certificate store to make this trusted.

When it comes to office environment it is better to contact the Administrator and add the certificate to all the systems (**certlm.msc** in run for **local machine** / **certmgr.msc** for **current user**) so your colleagues won't get this **dangerous site errors**.